# Отправка данных Ajax запросом при выборке значения из datalist

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Есть все области:

```
<input list="region" class="form-control" name="region">
<datalist id="region" >
    <?php foreach ($regions as $region){ ?>
    <option value="<?php echo $region['name']?>" selected="selected"><?php echo $region['name']?></option>
    <?php } ?>
</datalist>
```

Их можно выбирать как из выпадавшего списка, так и через строку поиска. А можно ли сделать так, чтобы данные отправлялись при выборе из списка? То есть
нажал - выпал список, выбрал область, и название области отправилось на сервер:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.form-control').change(function() {
        var regionid = $("input[name='region']").val();
        console.log(regionid);
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: '/index.php?route=checkout/checkout/region',
            data:{ "region_id":regionid},
            beforeSend: function() {
                $("#loader").css("display", "block");
                $("#loader").animate({ opacity: 1 }, 500);
            },
            success: function(data) {
                $('#div_city').html(data);
            }
        }).done(function(data) {
            $("#loader").animate({ opacity: 0 }, 500, function() {
                $("#loader").css("display", "none");
            });
        });
    });
});
```

Так отправляются после того как закрывается `input`. Выбрал, нажал на другой `input` или на другое место, и только тогда данные отправляются. `click` не получается - неправильные данные отправляются.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Так как к PHP вопрос, по сути, отношения не имеет, то вместо PHP кода имеет смысл вставить минимальный (2-3 `<option>`-a) пример итогового (отображаемого в браузере) HTML кода.

Comment: Да нужно, что бы так было, я спрашиваю можно ли так сделать, может так не будет работать.

Comment: Да, после выбора из выпадавшего пункта.

Comment: А что насчет впечатывания значения в `<input>` вручную? Просто есть простой вариант, при котором при выборе пункта запрос будет уходить сразу, однако в таком случае и при впечатывании каждого символа будет уходить запрос. Вас такой вариант устраивает?

Comment: Нет, а нельзя так сделать Впечатал несколько букв появились название областей и при клике на область она отправлялась на сервер?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Чтобы запрос уходил сразу при выборе пункта из списка, вместо события `change` можно использовать `input`.

А чтобы запрос не уходил при вводе каждого символа в `<input>`, можно делать проверку на то, что значение `<input>`-а совпадает со значением какого-либо `<option>`-а из `<datalist>`.

В итоге пример получается такой:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var regionIds = $("#region option").map(function() { return this.value; }).get();
  $('.form-control').on("input", function() {
    var regionId = this.value;
    if (regionIds.indexOf(regionId) < 0)
       return;
    $.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      url: '/sendurl',
      data: {
        "region_id": regionId
      }
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<input list="region" class="form-control" name="region">
<datalist id="region">
  <option value="name1">name1</option>
  <option value="name2">name2</option>
  <option value="name3">name3</option>
</datalist>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Спасибо за помощь все работает так как надо